# Which connector cable do I need to extract data for this nonfunctioning Seagate hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

**Edited:**

I have an old Seagate Barracuda 7200.11 hard drive (I removed it from the case) I would like to recover files from. But I am at a loss as to which connector and cable I would need; it does not appear to be standard.

(The drive stopped connecting to my machine one day. I assumed I needed to remove the drive from the case and pull the data using an adapter.)

Please see the attached images:
[image: drive case]
[image: power and usb port]
[image: sata image]
[image: sata image 2]
[image: hard drive label]

Comment: Option 1, as davidgo answered, is to remove the drive and use a SATA adapter. Make sure it's a powered adapter for 3.5-inch drives, e.g. [this one from Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00MVRS38G). Option 2 is to edit your question and add photos of the other connectors on the device. It might be standard USB and a place for a power adapter.

Comment: I edited the question a bit.

Comment: The USB connector looks like mini USB, and you can probably easily find a cable. The right power supply, however, might be harder to find. If you don't have access to the correct power supply, I would remove the drive at the SATA connector and use an adapter like I mentioned above.

Comment: So I have the USB and power cable, but the drive won't connect to any computer. I am assuming with the proper adapter I will be able to grab my data. So below Kara mentioned separating the green board from the drive. Is that what you mean by remove the drive at the SATA connector?

Comment: You don't need an adaptor - quite the opposite.  The drive currently has a SATA to mini USB adaptor attached. You just need to remove the adaptor to expose the SATA interface you need to plug it directly into your PC. (In other words you are not finished dismantling the drive)

Comment: davidgo, so gingerly peel back the green board?

Comment: @davidgo - You are correct if he has a desktop computer with an available 3.5-inch bay, SATA connection, and SATA cable. I was assuming he only has a laptop, which may or may not be true.

Comment: Yes. I imagine you can just unclip it, but I'm not sure if there are any screws holding it in on the back of the board.

Answer (score 3):

That drive is a standard SATA drive - see [https://www.amazon.com/ST3500820AS-9BX134-568-SD81-100468972-Seagate/dp/B00MANX8R2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MANX8R2)

I expect the bit you are missing is that there is a connector plugged into the SATA interface. You should be able to remove this and expose the actual interface.

Comment: This almost looks like a drive removed from an enclosure of some kind. Yes, I think the drive will separate cleanly from that green board.

Comment: I edited the question. Yes it was enclosed.

Comment: Yes, I was able to back the drive off the green board. Unfortunately, the drive is not showing up in Disk Management (using a Unitek adapter connection with power supply). I tried different usb ports and another computer, but it still does not show. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Your drive sounds stuffed. If the data is valuable take it to a professional recovery center.